# Audioplayer error Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method play on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers)

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I'm using dependency : audioplayers: ^0.20.1
And when I want to play a sound, I get his error :
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method play on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)

I already stopped and restart my emulator.

My code :

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 final player = AudioCache();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       body: SafeArea(
         child: FlatButton(
           child: Text("play "),
           onPressed: () {
             player.play('alarm.wav');
           },
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
} ```
````

Comment: Force Stop the running app, do `flutter pub get`, `invalidate cache & restart`.

Comment: I did a Flutter CLEAN and it works now ...